# Why does the user's password show when "login" button is pressed?

Tags: app-inventor

When the user with a preexisting account presses the login button for some reason the text on the login button changes to whatever password they typed in. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5v9G.png

[image]

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241383/login-signup-button-not-cooperating-on-mit-app-inventor-2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the green thing where you set `Login1.Text`.